# Finding misclassification rate in R...loan default

Tags: r

I have a data set with 10000 consumer loans and I created a model to predict whether a person will default or not, and the response variable is 1 (default) or 0 (did not default).  I used step() to find a glm model with a training set (8000 points) but my task is to determine the model's effectiveness at predicting default for the testing set (2000 points).  R is spitting out huge numbers when I try to get the error rate:

My reg has the Y response and 6 x variables.  This is how I'm trying to get the error rate:

```
preddreg <- predict(dreg, newdata=test, type="response")
predfull <- predict(full, newdata=test, type="response")
errorreg <- (test,1) - (preddreg = 1)
errorfull <- (test,1) - (predfull = 1)

mean(abs(errorreg))
##I keep getting 37, it should be a small decimal in the .20 range
mean(abs(error full))
##I get the same huge number
```

Is there an easier way to check a test set of data to get the misclassification rate?  I'm pulling my hair out and have spent 10 hours trying to get a reasonable error rate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `preddreg = 1` doesn't make a lot of sense here. If you're going for misclassification rate, you need to set a threshold for the predicted probabilities. Here's how to get the misclassifications for the `reg` model, using a threshold of `0.5`. Here, I assume `default` is the name of your outcome variable (I couldn't tell the name from reading your post):

```
preddreg <- predict(dreg, newdata=test, type="response")

# Rows are correct outcome, columns are prediction with threshold 0.5
tab <- table(test$default, preddreg >= 0.5)
tab   # Display the confusion matrix
accuracy.reg <- sum(diag(tab)) / sum(tab)
accuracy.reg  # Output accuracy
```

Comment: that fixed it, I thought it had to be = 1 since that is the value for "default"

Comment: Because you are using type="response", your model is reporting probabilities, so it's very unlikely the predicted probability will exactly equal 1. Even if you were checking for something exactly equalling 1, you would need to use "preddreg == 1" instead of "preddreg = 1"; the former compares for equality, while the latter assigns values.